# Install pip for new python version

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I installed Python3.11 which is located `usr/local/bin/python3`, which came without pip. The old Python3.10 was located in `usr/bin/python3`.
I tried to install pip with `sudo apt-install python3-pip`, but it seems to be attached to the old Python3.10. If I check `pip --version`, the output will be this:
`pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)`, but I need it for Python3.11. For example if I try to `pip install requests` now, I get `Requirements already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.25.1)`, which is the Python3.10 folder.

Comment: I would highly recommend conda to solve all of this mess altogether. You might try to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv):

> What pyenv does...
>
> - Lets you change the global Python version on a per-user basis.
> - Provides support for per-project Python versions.
> - Allows you to override the Python version with an environment variable.
> - Searches for commands from multiple versions of Python at a time. This may be helpful to test across Python versions with tox.

I'm using it to manage my virtual environments and my global environments

```bash
❯ pyenv global 3.10.5

❯ pyenv versions
  system
  3.7.10
* 3.10.5 (set by /home/xunjie/.pyenv/version)
  3.10.8

❯ which python
/home/xunjie/.pyenv/shims/python

❯ which pip   
/home/xunjie/.pyenv/shims/pip
```